# Just have one name appear for iOS app extension, not "App - Extension"?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

The developer guide mentions:

"An app extension needs a short, recognizable name that includes the name of the containing app, using the pattern 'Containing app name'—'App extension name'. This makes it easier for users to manage extensions throughout the system. **You can, optionally, use the containing app’s name as-is for your extension, in the common case that your containing app provides exactly one extension.**"

How do you make the extension show up as just 'Containing app name'? The guidelines don't really explain *how* to do this, just that it's possibly.

I couldn't just change the Bundle Display Name for the extension to an empty string "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the extension's name match the containing app's name and the extension portion will disappear when displayed.

Comment: So simple and yet why couldn't we just have left it empty and get the same result...